# take table from txt file and store it into array in c

Tags: c, stdin, argv

i have to create a c file that reads values from text file, and passes them into an array.
new to c.

file.txt to read from

```
 1989 500 222000
 1997 1500 180000
 1976 4000 20000
 1967 20000 10000
```

program should read table data from stdin. as follows (from the shell):
% ./tsort file.txt

my code so far

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
     FILE *inputFile;
     inputFile = fopen( argv[2], "r" );
     int number;

    while(fscanf(inputFile, "%i", number)==1)
    {
            printf("%i", number);
    }

return 0;

   }
```

Comment: In general we don't do your homework for you, but we will help you figure out why your attempt at solving the problem doesn't work. So, go ahead and give it your best effort and if you can't figure it out, ask again. A compilable example is a good place to start. whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: What do you already know how to do in C?

Comment: Some questions for you to think about:— Is this meant to be read into a 1D array or a 2D array?  Regardless of which, how are you going to allocate the array — as an ordinary local variable or dynamically with `malloc()`? And how are you going to ensure that you do not overflow the bounds of the array you read into? The answers will guide parts of your coding. Note that if you write `./tsort file.txt`, the data is not to be read from standard input; it is to be read from the file(s) specified on the command line. If it was to come from standard input, you'd write `./tsort < file.txt`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler
This is what i have so far, and it doesn't print anything, can you point on my problem? 

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) { 
FILE *inputFile; 
inputFile = fopen( argv[2], "r" ); 
int number; 
while(fscanf(inputFile, "%i", number)==1) { 
printf("%i", number); 
} return 0; }

Comment: @nike0505 - please edit your question - post your code there.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to use &number in the fscanf

Comment: @user814064 when i type  ./tsort file.txt , i get 
Segmentation fault

Comment: Because you need to do this `while(fscanf(inputFile, "%i", &number)==1)`

Comment: @user814064 yes i tried doing it with while(fscanf(inputFile, "%i", &number)==1)

Comment: Is the fileName is argv[2]? try argv[1]. argv[0] is the program name. Arrays start at zero in C.  If you printed out the program name, you'd see that.

Comment: @user814064 I tried playing around with argv[2],argv[1], argv[0]. and keep getting the same Segmentation fault

Comment: Your code now reads each number from the file in turn into variable `number`; that's good (though you should check that you were successful in opening the file before using the `FILE *`).  You are supposed to store those value in an array — and I see no array yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Note the & on number and the checking of the inputFile for null. The command line should be "./tsort file.txt"

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
     FILE *inputFile;
     int number;

     if(argc != 2) {
         printf("Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
         return 1;
     }
     inputFile = fopen(argv[1], "r" );

    if(inputFile == 0) {
        printf("Can't open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while(fscanf(inputFile, "%i", &number)==1)
    {
            printf("%i\n", number);
    }

    return 0;

   }
```